# Can we support the development of Economics.SE?

Tags: discussion

It is certain that most of the advanced economics questions are off-topic here, but we still got some of them. Apparently some of the users are likely to be future users of Economics.SE.

Maybe we can advertise Economics.SE here to accelerate its growth. After that, we can have an option to migrate the advanced economics questions to there and avoid conflict between users.

[Link to Economics.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics)

Answer (score 4):

Sure -- probably the best way to do this is to leave comments on such questions pointing them to the economics.se proposal and asking them to follow it and commit to it.

Comment: Is there any way to get the Economics proposal ad showing more often in the right sidebar, perhaps for any question here tagged with 'economics' or 'monetary-policy', say?